# How to type limit inferior

Tags: support, mathjax

How do I type the symbol for limit inferior on Math.SE? In general LateX, it needs the amsmath package. How do I type it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried doing `\liminf`? If I do this I get $\liminf$.

Comment: I did. However, owing to some other problems in the formula, it did not render correctly. I thought, the problem is due to this symbol.